# android viewpager webview div with scroll

Tags: android, scroll, xamarin, android-viewpager, android-webview

I'm using a ViewPager to display some local contents. These are html files so in every fragment i've got a webview using LoadDataWithBaseUrl() to visualize the correct page. So, I've got a  where there are some images and using swipe left/right is possibile to visualize all of them. it works in browser (desktop and mobile) and iOS but not here in Android. I've searched a lot and i understand i need to override the ViewPager, especially the canScrool method. This is my code:

public class BanjiViewPager : ViewPager
    {
        public BanjiViewPager (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        { }

```
    protected override bool CanScroll (Android.Views.View v, bool checkV, int dx, int x, int y)
    {
        if (v.GetType() == typeof(WebView)) {
            return ((WebView) v).CanScrollHorizontally(-dx);
        } else {
            return base.CanScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is this code (or others) checks if the webview is bigger than the fragment and let it to move to visualize all of it ( like zoom controls). In my case all the webview is visualize and i don't know where the  with images will be 'cause i've got some of them in different fragments. So is it possibile to override the method only with some ?

Thanks for the help

P.S: I'm using Xamarin Studio to develop this app but java source code is accepted as well!